# Firebase App registration empty "storageBucket"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to register a JavaScript project in firebase, I'm Getting the **Add Firebase to your web app** page with the details, but the **storageBucket** field is empty, from all the videos and text instructions I read I see that this field has value in it, I'm attaching a print screen of what I get bellow.
I want to say more, I created a firestore database, still the project on the **Add Firebase to your web app** is empty.

can any one help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time but when I looked on this app, I got the storage bucket with a URL.
So it's working now.